# Protect the images from downloading from the website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, image

As i know this is one of the common question, i almost got to know it is not possible to achieve 100%, but i want to protect image from normal users because for me there is no other choice

Anyway i am designing a product designing ecommerce website, where users used to design Business cards, Calendars in Online and they can buy it, i designed it using Wordpress, anyway i can work on PHP , Javascript and Jquery, So i need help based upon these 3 Languages

As you know it is based on printing , so i need to upload high resolution images in my website then only i can get better output for better printing

I almost protected my website from all the image theft options like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(png|jpg)$ - [F]
```

- Disable the direct image access in the htaccess file which shown above
- Right click is disabled
- Added watermarks in the Design Canvas preventing from screen capture or crop
- Hotlink protection is enabled for search engines and other sites linking my images

As almost everything i done in my website to prevent image from downloading

But i failed in one thing

[image]

I want to disable images tab in the frames in the Devtools and even in other browsers

So if this is done i can protect it from the normal users

How can i hide or disable this image tab from the user in the resource, because i have see in some of the websites it is disabled

Comment: `i have see in some of the websites it is disabled` - which sites? Knowing that may help in your quest for a solution

Comment: I don't remember but i cant see that tab in some websites, here it is one
https://img42.com/Xqpnh

Comment: Why don't you put watermark on all your product images ? or disable right click on images

Comment: Dilshan , i cant provide because i will also get ouput with water mark thats the problem while printing, i can provide it in design area as extra new layer but that will prevent only from screen capture

Comment: @musthafa - in firefox, the media can be seen in hte page info media tab, so you're not only fighting a losing battle, you're fighting it one browser at a time

Comment: Jaromanda at least i can concentrate on normal users , anyway we cant, google chorme highly used browsers, firefox page info media tab is not much know to normal users

Answer (score 0):

You can never truly protect your images from being accessible, infact what you are trying to do now is very browser and version specific which is not the best approach as well, infact you might want to go the standard approach which many of the popular websites do, (500px.com for example). Load standard quality images with watermarks and download and give the actual images on purchase, that way you do not end up coding and updating the code on every version change of chrome.

Comment: Kashyap i accept it but my website is something user customization website , i am not providing images directly , i will have layer of images like in photoshop where each layer is image , i need to protect that layered image thats where my problem lies